# phonegap - is ios or android device?

Tags: cordova

How can I tell if I'm running in ios7 (or any other env) ?

In IOS7 the topbar overlap with the app and mess up the view, I want to add a css class that will push the top bar 20px down only in ios7.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution would be to use a native [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/plugins/statusbar). 
If you're using `cordova` and `nodejs` run the following in your command line tool:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar`

Finally you need to invoke the function:

**vanilla JavaScript:**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
}, false);
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function(){
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
});
```

The `StatusBar` object has been added to the window namespace via the PhoneGap plugin system and you can access it via JavaScript. This way you can prevent the overlay on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try using cordova api : `device.platform` to check the OS and `device.version` to get the version of the OS.

Check Phonegap doc for reference : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.platform

Answer (score 0):

You can check which CSS hack works on iOS browser at: http://www.paulirish.com/demo/css-hacks and then provide custom solution for topbar